# Does GitHub Actions cache detect changes in the base Docker image?

Tags: docker, github, dockerfile, github-actions

I have a CI/CD pipeline in GitHub Actions. The pipeline builds and pushes a docker image to Docker Hub. To speed up the build, I have enabled the build cache in GitHub Actions, as detailed [here](https://docs.docker.com/ci-cd/github-actions/#optimizing-the-workflow).

The dockerfile uses an official **python:3.8-slim** from Docker Hub as a parent image.

Now say the parent image has some changes (e.g. a security fix). Will the GitHub Actions pull the correct version of the parent image (with the security fix)? Or will it automatically use the older version because of caching (pre security fix)?

Comment: Without an explicit pull (with `git pull` or an `imahePullPolicy: Always` or equivalent) there is no reason for Docker to update a local image. But the good thing is that if the image didn't change, an explicit pull won't be extensive operation, do you can do it.

Comment: 1. When you say local image - do you mean the image store on GitHub runner’s machine?

2. I think in my scenario the image will change because a security fix will entail a change - probably a different version of a library. This means one of the image layer’s will be different.

Comment: By "local image" I mean the image in the local cache of the docker daemon used (the result of `docker image ls`). The question is: do you want to get new update of the parent image if a new one is available? If yes, use explicit `docker image pull` or `docker image build --pull`, and the CI cache make you save time for every build while the parent image doesn't change.

Comment: Yes, if there is an update to the parent image, I would like to get it. My question is then, would the GitHub docker action, as shown [here](https://docs.docker.com/ci-cd/github-actions/#set-up-the-github-actions-workflow) would include the explicit `docker image pull` step if the CI cache is enabled?

Comment: In the documentation of the action https://github.com/docker/build-push-action#inputs there is a `pull` input for that which defaults to `false` (whatever CI cache)